# How to configure X kbmap for 4 languages while keeping two "main" languages easily switchable?

Tags: linux, xorg, setxkbmap

Now I have

```
setxkbmap -model acer_laptop -layout lang1,lang2 -variant ,
setxkbmap -option -option grp:caps_toggle
```

in a startup script. It works well for two languages.

I want to have 4 languages (like as in `-layout lang1,lang2,lang3,lang4`), hovewer I want Caps Lock to keep on switching between lang1 and lang2 and use some other method to loop thought all input languages.

How to do it? Can I call "setxkbmap" to only set current language (not affecting the Caps Lock cycle) so I can bind it to a keystroke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have bound the following script to a hotkey:

```
#!/bin/sh
if setxkbmap -query | grep -q lang1,lang2 ; then 
    setxkbmap -model acer_laptop -layout lang3,lang4 -variant , ;
else 
    setxkbmap -model acer_laptop -layout lang1,lang2 -variant , ;
fi
```